# Cast char subarray to integer

Tags: c

```
unsigned int b;
unsigned char a[] = 
{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x12,0x00,0x00,0x81,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x91,0x01,0x01,0xb1,0x04,0x47,0x86,0x8f,0xf8,0x00};
```

I'm a newbie in C programming,

I need to take the 4 bytes subarray start at a[18] which is 0x47868ff8,

and cast it into corresponding decimal integer:1200001016.

I try to use `memcpy(&b,a+18, 4)`, but it does not seem to work,

Could anyone give me some hints to work out this function?

And if I want to read a char pointer message then cast per 4 bytes in order into integer array,

what is the best way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is implementation-defined bevavior, and the result depends on the endianness of the processor.

Comment: `memcpy` This can only work for implementations where `unsigned` is 32-bit [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying like that has implementation-defined behavior, and you'll get different results depending on the endianness of the CPU.

To do it portably you can use bitwise operations.

```
b = (unsigned int)a[18] << 24 | (unsigned int)a[19] << 16 | (unsigned int)a[20] << 8 | a[21];
```